# Sencha Touch: Populating a store with Request headers/ data?

Tags: xml, ajax, proxy, sencha-touch, store

I am using Sencha Touch 2 for making an app. 
Currently I am sending an Ext.Ajax.Request to get an xml response.

```
    var header = {"ip-address":ipaddress ,"UserName" :    username ,"Password" : password };
        var data="XML Data " //some xml data ;


        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/Fluid/XmlServlet',
            headers: header,
            xmlData: data,
            method: 'post',

            success: function (response) {
//some success code
            },
            failure: function (response) {
//some failure code
            }
        });
```

So far, good. I get a XML response from the servlet perfectly. I can display it on the console. 
Now I want to populate a store using the XML Response I get. How do I do that? How do I pass the headers and the xmlData to the URL ? Is the URL fine?
I have tried googling about it, everywhere I see, the URL is generally an XML file on the local machine. Mine is an XML response object being returned from the URL '/Fluid/XmlServlet'. 
I am trying this.

```
Ext.define('SysMgr.store.Volumes', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'SysMgr.model.results',
        storeId: 'Volumes',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : '/Fluid/XmlServlet'', //Is this url fine? 
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: 'results',
                rootProperty: 'results'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Do any of the things change if I use JSON instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open or save the excel file attachment from the browser uisng ajax request in extjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609915/open-or-save-the-excel-file-attachment-from-the-browser-uisng-ajax-request-in-ex)