# Open or save the excel file attachment from the browser using ajax request in Ext.js

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

> I am generating the excel file in server side and writing it to the
>   outpuststream with the following response headers.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);
```

> In my client side : An ajax call to the servlet as shown :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'GenerateReport',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                'start_date': sd.getValue(),
                'end_date':ed.getValue()
            }
 });
```

> Browser shows following **Response Headers** :
>   [image]
>
> **My Issue :** The Open and Save dialog prompt is not opening.What may be the problem.Please help me resolve this.Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks @liya. I have resolved it by using iframe instead of ajax call.Its getting
>   downloaded directly.Here it is :

```
Ext.core.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
            tag : 'iframe',
            id : 'downloadIframe',
            frameBorder : 0,
            width : 0,
            height : 0,
            css : 'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',
            src : 'GenerateReport'
   });
```

> But Is their anyway,to open a dialog box before downloading,to prompt
>   for 'OPEN' or 'SAVE' the file instead of saving it directly which I am
>   doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open new window with appropriate URL instead of AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure the browser would prompt `Open` or `Save`, you have to send **binary** content type. Otherwise the browser tries to open the downloaded file with an associated application. Some browsers (older IE i.e.) might still infer the associated application from the filename extension.

> response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");